# check each alphabet and write text for each alphabet

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to Get result in the same way as show in the link of that picture. I tried many times to get that solution but could not able to find any solution for this problem. Link to the picture (http://haha123456.hol.es/death/abs2.jpg)

My html code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="result.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My php code is : result.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text = $_GET['name'] ;
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image); 
?>
```

and also i have created some array for each alphabet but only the thing is not getting right command to split the word which is given as an input and show some word from array according to each letter as given in the link picture.

Comment: Can you post your errors or what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

To split word by letter you can use

```
str_split($str);
```

To grab data from some array by first letter, first of all, I suggest using

```
array("a" => "Acrobat","b" => "bull");
```

And so on.

in that case, code would be:

```
$arr = array("a" => "Acrobat","b" => "bull");
$result = str_split($str);
foreach ($result as $letter) {
 echo $arr[$letter];
}
```

Comment: using your idea I have created this php coding

Comment: using your idea I have created this php coding `<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text = $_GET['name'] ;
$arr = array("a" => "Acrobat","b" => "bull");
$result = str_split($_GET['name']);
foreach ($result as $letter){
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $arr[$letter]);}
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image); 
?>`  It was working but the letters are appearing in the same area so its mixed up so can you help me

Comment: If I would create such functionality - I would avoid creating image, and output data using css.

<div>Sometext<div>

div {
    width: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

Also there is possibility to install [http://phantomjs.org/] and generate image.

If you really need image - you can increment "Y" parameter in imagettftext function like:

imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $arr[$letter]);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 100, $white, $font_path, $arr[$letter]);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 150, $white, $font_path, $arr[$letter]);

Comment: how to add more contents with naming "A" such as "Adorable" in this array `$arr = array("a" => "Acrobat","b" => "bull");` and also randomly select them

Comment: Add them as array, and use random to fetch one